# Rails controller params attribute not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, railstutorial.org, sorcery

Answered. See the end of post.

I am mainly a Java developer and fairly new to Ruby on Rails. I have successfully gone through the tutorial at railstutorial.org. So I got this to work once. My problem has come up when I started going through the tutorial a second time but this time trying to replace the authentication with the Sorcery gem. My main reference for that was [episode #283 on railscasts.org](http://railscasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery?view=asciicast). Some of it was working but when I try to sign in, I get an error saying:

> ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid in SessionsController#create
>
> missing value for :email in [:email] = :login

This was a difficult thing to search for since it is quite specific but with very general words that appear in a lot of places. I think I am doing things the same way as in the original tutorial when I had it working. Below is my views/sessions/new.html.erb which is just about the same as the original tutorial.

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  
      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the create method in my sessions_controller.rb which is a little different from the tutorial because of sorcery, but I don't know why params references are not working the same way as in the tutorial:

```
def create
  user = login(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
  if user
    redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The rails cast just uses params[:email] but that was because he used form_tag instead of form_for and changed which param to use.

I'm really lost here. Not sure why it isn't working the same as the tutorial. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I should provide any additional information. Thanks.

EDIT:
Added the full error above. It must be some problem with sorcery's login method or my database. The parameters are coming through fine. Here's the full stack trace (back to my part of the code. It's really too long beyond that.)

Stack trace:

> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:141:in `block in replace_named_bind_variables'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:135:in `gsub'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:135:in `replace_named_bind_variables'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:115:in `sanitize_sql_array'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:28:in `sanitize_sql_for_conditions'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:324:in `build_where'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:136:in `where'
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `where'
>
> sorcery (0.7.13) lib/sorcery/model/adapters/active_record.rb:32:in `find_by_credentials'
>
> sorcery (0.7.13) lib/sorcery/model.rb:108:in `authenticate'
>
> sorcery (0.7.13) lib/sorcery/controller.rb:33:in `login'
>
> app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'

I guess I'm too new to answer my own question right away. Fixed it myself:

In sorcery.rb, I had:

user.username_attribute_names = '[:email]'

Apparently, the quotes shouldn't be there. I was confused by the comments in the file. After I made that change I needed to restart the server for the change to take effect.

Comment: The first debugging step would be to make sure what is in params. Look in your log `log/development.log` and you should be able to see the request. That will show you the parameters coming in from the request and would be very useful to help debug and ensure that the fields you expect are where you expect them.

Comment: Yes, I had looked at that. Here it is. Even though email is blank, it is still part of the session object:  

Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nq4t8lAcEnPVsNxhNgz7+J7/IXQaQuoHiuMM8YZfM+U=", "session"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}

Comment: And what does the stack trace for the error look like?

Comment: could you try with @session instead of :session?

Comment: @session doesn't work. 
Not sure how to get more of a stack trace but in the log file it just says:
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (missing value for :email in [:email] = :login):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'

line 7 is the line: "user = login...."

Comment: could you change form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) to form_for @session , and make sure "new" in your controller initializes "@session".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself:

In sorcery.rb, I had:

user.username_attribute_names = '[:email]'

Apparently, the quotes shouldn't be there. I was confused by the comments in the file. After I made that change I needed to restart the server for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I see source code of sorcery. And username_attribute_names Should be a Array.

And this is in sorcery/spec/rails3/spec/controller_spec.rb:

sorcery_model_property_set(:username_attribute_names, [:username, :email])

It will be called by :
def find_by_credentials(credentials)
  sql = @sorcery_config.username_attribute_names.map{|attribute| column_name(attribute) + " = :login"}
  where(sql.join(' OR '), :login => credentials[0]).first
end

So , try

user.username_attribute_names = [:email]
or sorcery_model_property_set(:username_attribute_names, [ :email])